# AutoFac Autowiring Conventions

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

StructureMap has the ability to apply conventions when scanning. Thus IFoo => Foo, without explicit registration.

Is something simular available in AutoFac? Looked around and just can't find anything helpfull.

Thanks,

Comment: could you expand a little bit on what you mean by "autowiring"?

Comment: Hm.. Do you mean that StructureMap will automatically look for a class named Foo when a resolve for IFoo is performed?

Answer (score 17):

#### For Autofac versions from v2

The new [scanning features](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning) in Autofac2 will imo remove some of the need for registration-by-convention. Lets say that `Foo` lives in Plugins.dll:

```cs
var assembly = Assembly.Load("Plugins");
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

This registration will pick up `Foo` and register it as `IFoo`.

#### For Autofac versions less than v2

You can use the ContainerBuilder.RegisterTypesMatching. Here's an example:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterTypesMatching(type => type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IFoo)));
var container = builder.Build();

var foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Peter, what he means is default convention scanning that is available in StructureMap. It automatically binds IX and X where X is a class that implements interface IX. It works like this:

```cs
public override void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
{
    if (!type.IsConcrete()) return;

    Type pluginType = FindPluginType(type);
    if (pluginType != null && Constructor.HasConstructors(type))
    {
        registry.AddType(pluginType, type);
        ConfigureFamily(registry.For(pluginType));
    }
}

public virtual Type FindPluginType(Type concreteType)
{
    string interfaceName = "I" + concreteType.Name;
    Type[] interfaces = concreteType.GetInterfaces();
    return Array.Find(interfaces, t => t.Name == interfaceName);
}
```

I would also like to know if Autofac supports a similar thing. StructureMap lets you define your own IRegistrationConvention's. This is one example of a convention.

Comment: The new assembly scanning feature (http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning) in Autofac2 probably covers a lot of ground here. See my updated answer.